# How to make a Fortran type-bound procedures in a parametrized derived type?

Tags: pointers, fortran, derived-types

I'm trying to understand better how pointers work on fortran and how can be used to be argument of another functions. The program works as follows: it has three entries, `r0,rf` and `long`. Then the function `linspace` generates an equispaced array from `r0` to `rf`. Then the second function should take as input the radius values and take the square of each value and generate a new array. Here is the code

```
module class_Circle
 use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only: dp => real64
implicit none

 type, public :: Circle(long)
  integer,len :: long
  real(dp) :: r0,rf
 contains
  procedure  :: radius =>linspace
  procedure :: area => circle_area
 end type Circle

contains

 function linspace(this) result(radius)
  class(Circle(*)),intent(inout) :: this
  real(dp),dimension(this%long) :: radius
  integer :: i
  real(dp) :: incremento,b
  incremento = (this%rf-this%r0)/(1.0d0*(this%long-1))
  b = (this%r0*this%long-this%rf)/(1.0d0*(this%long-1))
  do i = 1,this%long
    radius(i) = b+incremento*i
  end do
 end function linspace

 function circle_area (this) result(area)
  class(Circle(*)), intent(inout) :: this
  real (dp), dimension(this%long):: area
  integer :: i
  real(dp), parameter :: pi =dacos(-1.0d0)
  do  i = 1,this%long 
    area(i) = pi * this%radius(i)**2
  end do
 end function circle_area

end module class_Circle

program circle_test
use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only: dp => real64
use class_Circle
implicit none

integer,parameter :: long = 3
type(Circle(long)) :: c
c%r0 = 1.5d0
c%rf = 3.0d0

print*, c%radius()
print*, c%area()
end program circle_test
```

When I compile it `gfortran-8` I get the following errors

```
      area(i) = pi * this%radius(i)**2.0d0
                               1
Error: ‘radius’ at (1) is not a member of the ‘Pdtcircle’ structure
objecttest03.f90:10:15:

   procedure :: area => circle_area
           1
Error: Argument ‘this’ of ‘circle_area’ with PASS(this) at (1) must be of        
the derived-type ‘circle' objecttest03.f90:9:15:

   procedure  :: radius =>linspace
           1
Error: Argument ‘this’ of ‘linspace’ with PASS(this) at (1) must be of the   derived-type ‘circle’
```

I don't understand the first error because it's defined in the class. Also I guess that the following errors are because of this one, so how can I make this work? And also a related question, can I point to a procedure in different modules?

Comment: The function `linspace` hasn't an argument corresponding to the `i` you attempt to have with the line where the error is reported.

Comment: @francescalus so i can get the element `this%radius` but I can't get in this way any of its elements?

Comment: The function returns an array, so you should assign the result to an array, or use it in an expression in which an array is approrpiate

Comment: @IanBush doesn't `real (dp), dimension(this%long):: area`  in the function `circle_area`do assign the result to an array in the same way the function `linspace` does?

Comment: Not sure I understand, but probably no, what I can see assigns one element at a time - I'm talking about using a bit of basic array syntax, not a do loop in sight

Comment: @IanBush ok I get it, but how can I get an element of the array?

Comment: array = function_that_returns_array(); element = array( i )      I have to say it, if you can't get that you would better spend your time studying some of the more fundamental parts of Fortran than trying to sort out how to use parametrised derived types and type bound functions - your code above seems to be a strange mixture of Fortran 66/77 and 2003 and missing out a lot in between. I'll also note that while your question mentions pointers, there isn't a pointer in sight in this example.